# Losing data when copy pasting from txt to excel and running text to column function

Tags: excel, vba

I have rows of data separated with a comma stored in a txt file.

The issue I have is when I copy the data into an excel and do text to columns function, I'm losing a piece of the data. `Security ID` is always a length of 9 characters, but if it contains only numbers and has zeroes at the beginning, once I paste into excel the data is treated as a number and the zeroes disappear

e.g. The data I have in txt file (`Security ID` field is the issue)

```
Security  ID        Symbol     SMF SOURCE   ISSUE TYPE              PRICE   YIELD
000384526           PortDflt                Equity - Common Stk     85.365  0
```

e.g. what I get when I copy paste into excel

```
Security  ID        Symbol     SMF SOURCE   ISSUE TYPE              PRICE   YIELD
384526              PortDflt                Equity - Common Stk     85.365  0
```

I tried a workaround with the following formula, but as Security IDs are treated like a number, I also get the issue of having results like this `2.361E+111` and the below formula becomes useless

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<9,REPT(0,9 - LEN(A2))&A2,A2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record a macro that does the text to columns but make sure you select Text in step 3 on the column(s) you need to preserve the format of.

[image]

You simply click on the column you want to change cell format on and select text at the top left.
The code I recorded while doing this is:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

And it's the FieldInfo that is what cell format the column should have.  Array(1,2) means the first column (A), should have 2 (Text) as format.